# Not entering the created record in the list form in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

In my home page i have to create records and when i am creating the records and clicking on submit button and getting like added successfully. After that the created record is not available in the list records.When i'm creating another new record and submit it the previous created record is displays in the list.

Type Script code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { VisitService } from '../shared/visit.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Response, RequestOptions, Http, Headers  } from '@angular/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-visit',
  templateUrl: './visit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./visit.component.css']
})
export class VisitComponent implements OnInit {
  cookieValue = 'UNKNOWN';
  constructor(private visitService: VisitService,private http: Http,private cookieService: CookieService, private toastr: ToastrService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('session');
    console.log('token from browser' + this.cookieValue );
    const url = `http://localhost:8080//api/getallvisits/`;
  // const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization':'Bearer' +this.cookieValue});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.cookieValue });
 // const headers = new Headers();
 // headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer' +this.cookieValue );
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(url, options)

    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log('message from' + res);
     // this.refresh();
      alert('successfullyyy...');
     // console.log('message from' + people.json())
    });
  }
  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
    form.reset();
    this.visitService.selectedVisit = {
      'ID':null,
      'UserName': '',
      'Height': null,
      'Weight': null,
      'Temperature': null,
      'BloodPressure': '',
      'PatientNote': '',
      'NurseNote': '',
      'DoctorNote': '',
    }
  }
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.ID == null) { 
      this.visitService.createVisit(form.value)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.resetForm(form);
          this.visitService.getVisitList();
          this.toastr.success('New Record Added Succcessfully', 'Employee Register');
        })
    }
   else {
      this.visitService.updateVisit(form.value.ID, form.value)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.visitService.getVisitList();
        this.toastr.info('Record Updated Successfully!', 'Employee Register');
      });
    }
  }

}
```

And my HTML page is:

```
<form class="visit-form" #visitForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(visitForm)">
  <input type="hidden" name="ID" #ID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.ID">
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="UserName" name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.username"
         placeholder="User Name" required>
       <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="UserName.invalid && UserName.touched">This Field is Required.</div>
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Height" name="Height" #Height="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.height" placeholder="Height"
         required>
       <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="Height.invalid && Height.touched">This Field is Required.</div>
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Temperature" name="Temperature" #Temperature="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.temperature" placeholder="Temperature">
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Weight" name="Weight" #Weight="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.weight" placeholder="Weight">
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Blood Pressure" name="BloodPressure" #BloodPressure="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.bloodpressure" placeholder="Blood Pressure">
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Patient Note" name="PatientNote" #PatientNote="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.patientnote" placeholder="Patient Note">
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Nurse Note" name="NurseNote" #NurseNote="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.nursenote" placeholder="Nurse Note">
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
       <input class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Doctor Note" name="DoctorNote" #DoctorNote="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="visitService.selectedVisit.doctornote" placeholder="Doctor Note">
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-8">
       <button [disabled]="!visitForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">
         <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Submit</button>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-secondary" (click)="resetForm(visitForm)">
         <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Reset</button>
     </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Anyone please refer that.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

See if you are displaying the value in html table or like that then after submit you have to destroy the table .

and again Reinit the table then only it will display the current added value  as well.

So You can do that or else call the onload function when submit function ends .

or if you have some other issue then let me know in details.

Comment: Thanks for reply, You mean that in html page want to add list code .Is it right.

Comment: i mean where you are listing the data is it in html table or datatable or gridview , so in that on submit u have to update the value . that is why i told you to do destroy the table on submit end then reinit the table again or use the reinit function